# Identify this bush with an interesting smell

Tags: united-states, plant-identification

I've seen this bush both in the Denver CO and in the Amarillo TX area. It has a pleasant warm smell. The specimen photoed is about 6 ft tall and 6 ft wide though I don't know how much bigger it might get.

I'm trying using those planned identification apps with little success, I got results such as white willow which this plant clearly is not, based on comparing photos.

In Denver it grows in a mostly uncultivation area next to an unused irrigation canal, but could be an invasive or a transplant. Bark is smooth and the leaves are thin and fold easily without snapping. The smell comes from the bush in general not from any apparent blooms or from disturbing the leaves.

[image: Photo of leaves]
[image: Photo of branches]

Comment: Where is it growing? Somewhere truly wild or somewhere that could have been cultivated?  Can you get close enough to the  trunk or a major branch to get a photo of the bark?  Is it the leaves that smell, when crushed (and how do they crush - they look like they'd snap if you folded them in half)?

Comment: It should eventually produce flowers, which will make it much easier for the plant apps to identify what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [laurel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurus_nobilis). When you have some bay leaves close at hand you could go there and make a comparison.

If it is not a bay laurel chances are it is a closely [related species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_plants_known_as_laurel).

Comment: Laurel / bay leafs are not thin and easily bendable. So I doubt you are right.

Comment: @Willeke you've seen to many supermarket bay leaves. Real bay leaves rather than bent can grow a little bit contorted. Anyway it could still be a related species.

Comment: I have had the pleasure to know a bay tree, took it up a Ferris wheel the day we met.